# Bolt CMS: Page revisions

Tags: plugins, bolt-cms

I'm trying to find a 3rd party plugin or method for getting Bolt CMS to save a revision every time you update a page, much like wordpress does out of the box. However, after some fairly intensive googling I haven't found anything.

Perhaps 'page revisions' and 'page versioning' are the wrong things to search for. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "`changelog:`" in your main config (`app/config/config.yml`)